# Expression-Bodied Function combined with Auto Properties results in problems

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0, .net-4.6

After finally upgrading to VS2015 and starting utilizing .NET4.6, I have been utilizing some of the syntactic sugar when I have come across old classes.

Unfortunately, this doesn't always go smooth :/ An example of this, is the following example.

I have this existing code that works.

```
private static string _bootstrapBundle;
public static string BootstrapBundle
{
    get
    {
        return _bootstrapBundle;
    }
}
```

A quick rewrite to use expression body gives me this, which works

```
private static string _bootstrapBundle;
public static string BootstrapBundle => _bootstrapBundle;
```

This can also be rewritten to use auto properties, like the following code which works

```
public static string BootstrapBundle { get; private set; }
```

If I try to take it a step further, and write the following, it doesn't work

```
private static string _bootstrapBundle;
public static string BootstrapBundle { get; private set; } = _bootstrapBundle;
```

All three examples of code compiles just fine, but when I later on try to assign a value like the following, it's only with the last piece of code that it fails to assign anything to BootstrapBundle.

```
BootstrapBundle = SquishIt.Framework.Bundle.Css()
                    .Add("/assets/stylesheets/Theme/" + theme + "/Bootstrap/bootstrap.less")
                    .Render("/assets/Cache/bootstrap.css");
```

How can this be? Are the expressions resolved differently? At different times? Am i abusing the syntax?

Comment: You say the last piece of code doesn't work. Can you explain what you mean by that? What behavior did you expect here that didn't work? I ask because it compiles and runs just fine, and does what is expected (by me at least).

Comment: That last one isn't setting up your property to use that field.  It's just initializing it.  You'd still have to set it via the property, thus there's no point in even having the field.

Comment: My apologies, I had completely forgotten to tell about what I was using the code for. The question have now been updated with info about that :)

Comment: Please don't post a moving target question. Again you have chosen to *not* say what "doesn't work". The code fails to work in production... **what does that mean?** I chose to delete my answer as it seems the answer is no longer relevant to the question.

Comment: Sorry @LasseV.Karlsen I tried to explaing it, but I think bottomline is that with my last example, I cannot assign BootstrapBundle as I can in the two previous ones.

Comment: The last example should work just fine. You've initialized the autoproperty to a null reference (since you never gave `_bootstrapBundle` a value), and then you later on assign it a real value with the last piece of code. Barring a catastrophic compiler failure, this should just work. Can you show a [mcve]? Those pieces may look all well and good but if you place them in the wrong place something then we can't tell since you don't show the whole picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go though the options you gave one by one and look at what each does:

1. ```
   private static string _bootstrapBundle;
   public static string BootstrapBundle
   {
       get
       {
           return _bootstrapBundle;
       }
   }
   ```

   I'm assuming that I don't have to explain what this does. But note that if you try to assign to `BootstrapBundle`, it will fail at compile time, since there is no setter. But you can work around that by assigning directly to the field.
2. ```
   private static string _bootstrapBundle;
   public static string BootstrapBundle => _bootstrapBundle;
   ```

   This is exactly the same as #1, only with more succinct syntax.
3. ```
   public static string BootstrapBundle { get; private set; }
   ```

   Here we have an auto-property, that is a property with hidden (unspeakable) backing field. It compiles to:

   ```
   private static string <BootstrapBundle>k__BackingField;
   public static string BootstrapBundle
   {
       get
       {
           return <BootstrapBundle>k__BackingField;
       }
       private set
       {
           <BootstrapBundle>k__BackingField = value;
       }
   }
   ```

   This means that setting the property now works and getting it after setting will give you the new value.
4. ```
   private static string _bootstrapBundle;
   public static string BootstrapBundle { get; private set; } = _bootstrapBundle;
   ```

   This is the same as #3, except that the hidden backing field is initialized to the value you gave:

   ```
   private static string _bootstrapBundle;
   private static string <BootstrapBundle>k__BackingField = _bootstrapBundle;
   public static string BootstrapBundle
   {
       get
       {
           return <BootstrapBundle>k__BackingField;
       }
       private set
       {
           <BootstrapBundle>k__BackingField = value;
       }
   }
   ```

   What this means is that there are now two fields: one hidden and one visible. The hidden field will initially be set to the value of the visible field (which is `null`), but after that, the two fields won't affect each other.

   This means that if you set the property, and then get the property, you will get the updated value. But if you read the visible field, its value won't be updated. And vice versa: if you update the field, the value of the property won't change.

Comment: Well, it makes sense, but now I don't understand why I previously have been able to set BootstrapBundle, why I can set it in example #1 & #2.
As i see it, the first code that I hade written shouldn't work as I shoudln't be able to set BootstrapBundle, right?

Comment: @Squazz Yeah, exactly. The next time, it would help if you provided a [mcve].

Comment: I will try to create one later today. This problem puzzles me. At the moment, from what I can see it works when it should't, and it doesn't work when it should :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the behavior to be exactly the same, you have these two options:

1. With expession body (like you offered, and with no other refactoring needed):

   ```
   private static string _bootstrapBundle;
   public static string BootstrapBundle => _bootstrapBundle;
   ```
2. With auto properties (like you also suggested, here you have to refactor all assignments to use the property rather than the field variable):

   ```
   public static string BootstrapBundle { get; private set; }
   ```

The reason why your last example did not work, is that the field variable does not have a value when you try to assign it, where as using expression body, the getter is resolved every time you access the property, and assignment can be delayed. Put in other words, it works as readonly, and assignment of the variable has to happen inside a constructor, making the field variable useless, unless you want to use it for other methods (which would be completely unreadable and a terrible debugging experience!) :)

If you want your last example to work, you have to use a constant instead:

```
public static string BootstrapBundle { get; private set; } = "42";
```

but if you do not need the default value not much changes for you, and you might as well leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of defining the property:

```
// this defines a public getter, public setter property with no backing field (there is an internal one, but not one you can access)
public static string BootstrapBundle {
    get;
    set;
} 

// this defines a public getter, public setter property with a backing field
private static string _bootstrapBundle = "42";
public static string BootstrapBundle {
    get {
        return _bootstrapBundle;
    }
    set {
        _bootstrapBundle = value;
    }
}

//this defines a no setter property with a backing field
private static string _bootstrapBundle = "42";
public static string BootstrapBundle {
    get {
        return _bootstrapBundle;
    }
}
```

using C#6 features:

```
// this sets a getter only property that returns the current value of _bootstrapBundle (equivalent to the last form in the code above)
private static string _bootstrapBundle = "42";
public static string BootstrapBundle => _bootstrapBundle;

// this sets up an auto property (no backing field) that at initialization gets the initial value of _bootstrapBundle
private static string _bootstrapBundle = "42";
public static string BootstrapBundle {get;set;} = _bootstrapBundle;

// equivalent to this:
public static string BootstrapBundle {get;set;} = "42";
```

Since you are setting the property in your code, it means you need a setter. If all what you wanted is a property with a backing field, you have no C#6 syntax to replace the good old `return _backingField;/_backingField=value`

Comment: Trying to do the last thing you you mention, it won't compile. I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol _bootstrapBundle" :)

About the first example, here I don't see how it differs from the code that doesn't work in my case?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? A property that gets initialized at startup with the value in a field (that should have been initialized itself) or an auto property that has a backing field?

Comment: try looking at my question again (the last part), updated it with more information about this. I hope in answers your question :)